# Are there any non-stationary asymptotically flat and geodesic complete solutions to the vacuum Einsteins's field equations

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, differential-geometry

I read the book *The global nonlinear stability of the minkowski space* by Christodoulou, D., and Klainerman, S.

In the Chapter I, Page 10 it says:

*“However, it remains questionable whether there exists any nontrivial6 solution of the field equations that satisfies the Penrose requirements. Indeed, his regularity assump­tions translate into fall-off conditions of the curvature that may be too stringent and thus may fail to be satisfied by any solution that would allow gravitational waves.”*

So I am curious about if anyone had found such solutions above that is non-stationary asymptotically flat and geodesic completeness.

Thank you.

Comment: A geon solution?